# Jquery .after function

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Below code is from `.aspx` file

```
<div class="clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
   <span class="spinfo">Name:</span>
   <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtname"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
```

And below code is from `.css` file:

```
.spana1{
    background-position: left center;
    color: #c80000;
    background-image: url('symbol-error.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 17px; 
}
```

And Below code is from `.js` file

```
var error = true;    
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtname").focusout(function () {
        error = false;
        $(".spana1").remove();
        if ($("#txtname").val() == "") {
            $("#txtname").after("<span class='spana1'>Please Enter your Name</span>");
            error = true;
        }
    });
});
```

When `#txtname` lose focus if its content equal null , this raw should be called : `$("#txtname").after("<span class='spana1'>Please Enter your Name</span>");`

But result is so :

[image: Result]

But I used `.after` . When I try `.before` result is the same.

What could be reasons?

Comment: use .append it will do it

Comment: @Mustafa M Jalal , I tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `floating` of `input element` using **CSS** like,

```
#txtname{
   float:left;
}
```

Also use `$(this)` instead of reusing the same selector again and again like,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtname").focusout(function () {
        error = false;
        $(".spana1").remove();
        if (this.value == "") { // you can use $(this).val() also
            $(this).after("<span class='spana1'>Please Enter your Name</span>");
            error = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, also thanks your advice for .js  .  
Can you explain why my result was so ?
If I don't use float:left, It could be bottom of TextBox , but why before ? 
I'll accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: It is because of floating on `span element` if you inspect it in console, then you can see it. And after applying float on `input` then it will show in `left first` before your error element.